# Unwanted second line in stream writer

Tags: c#

I am coding a program, and i use stream writer, to write text to some files. The problem is, that when it writes to the text file, it leaves an unwanted extra line to the file, which confuses my program, when try to read it later. An example of the stream writer that i use is this:

```
string enbl = "Enabled = false;";
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("path");
file.WriteLine(enbl);

file.Close();
```

Is it possible ti fix that ?

Comment: Well, that has one line and a line terminator at the end. If you don't want the line terminator, use `file.Write(enbl);` instead of `WriteLine`. Or just use `File.WriteAllText` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dont want that the output get an implicit CR+LF (0x0D + 0x0A) at the end you have to you use `file.Write(enbl);` instead of `file.WriteLine(enbl);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use Write instead of WriteLine method.